# Oracle to_date: ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: oracle, date-formatting, to-date

How can I convert this string to a date or timestamp?

'04-Nov-2014 10:16:20 AM -0500'

I tried:

```
select to_date('04-Nov-2014 10:16:20 AM -0500', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM TZH') FROM dual;
```

which gives error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type `DATE` does not support any time zone information, thus you must use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` if you like to use it. Also you should consider the date language which is set by current user NLS-Settings.

Then `-5000` does not match `TZH`, try this one:

```
select 
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04-Nov-2014 10:16:20 AM -0500', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM TZHTZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') 
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm), which can parse timezone information:

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04-Nov-2014 10:16:20 AM -0500', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM TZHTZM')
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

Oracle dates do not persist any timezone information, so you must use timestamp.